# "qtCored4.dll was not found" when running the application outside console.what could be wrong?

Tags: qt

when running the application from inside the mingw console, it executes without any issue. But when I try to execute the same exe file in the debug folder of windows explorer, it says **QtCored4.dll was not found.** I even added the bin folder location to the environment variables, but then that produces another error saying : **The procedure entry point _Z5qFreePv could not be located in the dynamic link lib...** .So, can anyone give me a hint on how to solve this problem? Thanks.

Comment: Searching for "_Z5qFreePv" on Google gives a lot of hits about the wrong versions of the DLLs being loaded at runtime. Have you tried copying the Qt DLLs to your exe folder? Did you add the correct bin folder location to the environment variables (I assume you mean the PATH environment variable)?

Comment: yes, i mean the PATH variable.

Comment: Do you have different version of Qt on your pc? It seems to me that MinGw compiles with a different Qt version from the one you linked in the path variable.

Comment: yes, I have two versions 4.7.4 and 4.8.1; one was installed with Qt SDK, and the other I had already installed on my system. How can I find out which version of Qt is used for compilation???

Answer (score 0):

As nax83 pointed out above, the problem was the **path variable ambiguity due to multiple version of qt installed** on my system. I removed all other qt-related values from my path variable and then explicitly specified all the paths to one single version. Recompiled and built the application, and there was my application, running without any jerks and problems.